# Does CLR makes database like queries during the JIT compilation?

Tags: .net, database, compilation, clr, jit

Does CLR makes database like queries before the JIT compilation?

I am reading the **CLR via C#** book. I come across the description of the **TypeDef** definition table:

> Contains one entry for each type defined in the module. Each entry includes the type’s name,
>   base type, and flags (public, private, etc.) and contains indexes to the methods it owns in the
>   MethodDef table, the fields it owns in the FieldDef table, the properties it owns in the
>   PropertyDef table, and the events it owns in the EventDef table.

The presence of the indexes makes me think that during the  JIT compilation the CLR will uses the non-clustered indexes in the **TypeDef** table to quickly access the entries in the **MethodDef**, **FieldDef**, **PropertyDef** and in the **EventDef**. Just like it happens in databases. I.e. that each entry in the **TypeDef** contains 4 tables (because a non-clustered index is a table).

Do I understand it correctly or do the indexes mean something else here?

Comment: That's roughly correct.  Metadata is painfully micro-optimized to be as small as possible.  The CLR does not deal with it directly, there is an extra layer that is normally implemented by the host.  Since it is useful to other tools, it [is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadataimport-interface).

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you. You comment suffices as an answer.